# Stanford NLP sentiment running error

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I downloaded Stanford NLP 3.5.2 at http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-corenlp-full-2015-04-20.zip

Then I unzip the file and move to the new unzip directory.

I ran as instructed at:

http://nlp.stanford.edu/sentiment/code.html

`java edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.Evaluate edu/stanford/nlp/models/sentiment/sentiment.ser.gz test.txt`

Then I have an error:

`"Error: Could not find or load main class edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.Evaluate"`

Followed with some instructions in stackoverflow, I used:

`java -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.Evaluate edu/stanford/nlp/models/sentiment/sentiment.ser.gz test.txt`

Then I have another problem:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.getInputStreamFromURLOrClasspathOrFileSystem(IOUtils.java:461)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.readObjectFromURLOrClasspathOrFileSystem(IOUtils.java:313)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentModel.loadSerialized(SentimentModel.java:627)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.Evaluate.main(Evaluate.java:72)
```

How should I fix the problem? (I am using Java 8 1.8.0_25 on Mac)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://nlp.stanford.edu/sentiment/code.html) is not up to date. The [javadoc](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/sentiment/Evaluate.html) says that you have to add `-model` and `-treebank` before the corresponding files:

```
java -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.Evaluate -model edu/stanford/nlp/models/sentiment/sentiment.ser.gz -treebank test.txt
```

Comment: Hi, but I want to run the evaluation tool mentioned http://nlp.stanford.edu/sentiment/code.html

Comment: @mamatv I've modified my answer

Comment: Hi Ortomala, it's great, I can run the evaluation now, but the result appeared on my computer is different from what they reported from the paper. Is it true?

Comment: @mamatv I think the best is to ask a new question detailing the settings of your experiment and the differences you observe between your results and the results published in the paper.